# Errors importing Networkx package

Tags: python, sphinx, networkx, conda

For some reason I'm unable to import networkx. Here is the error I get when I try to import within Python in interactive mode.

```
>>> import networkx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\wkong\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\networkx\__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
    import networkx.drawing
  File "C:\Users\wkong\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\networkx\drawing\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import nx_pydot
  File "C:\Users\wkong\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pydot.py", line 27, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import parse_version
  File "C:\Users\wkong\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\eda\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3086, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "C:\Users\wkong\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\eda\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3070, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\wkong\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\eda\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3114, in _initialize_
    for dist in working_set
  File "C:\Users\wkong\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\eda\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3114, in <genexpr>
    for dist in working_set
  File "C:\Users\wkong\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\eda\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2637, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "C:\Users\wkong\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\eda\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2174, in declare_name
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "C:\Users\wkong\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\eda\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2094, in _handle_ns
    loader = importer.find_module(packageName)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 426, in _find_module_shim
ImportWarning: Not importing directory C:\Users\wkong\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\sphinxcontrib: missing __init__
```

I'm running Anaconda on Win7 and have also re-installed networkx. Running networkx-2.1 right now. Again, this was working just fine yesterday.

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing networkx via conda and it has not helped.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by uninstalling `networkx` via `conda` and `pip`. I must have installed `networkx` using both methods and something finally broke.

Steps:

- `conda uninstall networkx`
- `pip uninstall networkx`
- `conda install -c anaconda networkx`

I no longer get errors when importing `networkx`